# Dúvida mysql SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Pessoal estou com uma dúvida, segue o `SELECT` abaixo:

```
    SELECT 
    o.matricula, 
    v.cd_operador, 
    o.hora, 
    c.nm_nome, 
    COALESCE(SUM(o.quantidade), 0) AS sacolax, 
    v.sas03 AS sas03, 
    COALESCE(SUM(o.quantidade), 0) - v.sas03 divergencia
     FROM sacolax_tb_operacao o 
     LEFT JOIN ( 
         SELECT o.cd_matricula, 
         o.cd_operador, 
         COALESCE(SUM(v.qtd), 0) AS sas03 
         FROM sacolax_tb_venda v 
         LEFT JOIN sacolax_tb_operador o ON v.cd_operador = o.cd_operador 
         WHERE dt_venda = '2020-05-14' 
         GROUP BY cd_matricula ) v ON v.cd_matricula = o.matricula 
    LEFT JOIN tb_colaboradores c ON o.matricula = c.cd_matricula 
    WHERE DATE(hora) = '2020-05-14' 
    GROUP BY o.matricula 
    ORDER BY hora DESC;
```

Como resultado:

```
matricula   cd_operador hora    nm_nome sacolax sas03   divergencia
295888  5888    2020-05-14 16:00:36 OPERADOR1   49  49  0
106328  6328    2020-05-14 15:54:47 OPERADOR2   47  47  0
```

como faço para ter retorno de mais dias, sem ter soma entre os dias nas colunas sacolax e sas03? Como abaixo:

```
matricula   cd_operador hora    nm_nome sacolax sas03   divergencia
295888  5888    2020-05-11 16:00:36 OPERADOR1   20  20  0
295888  5888    2020-05-14 16:00:36 OPERADOR1   49  49  0
106328  6328    2020-05-14 15:54:47 OPERADOR2   47  47  0
```

Obs: o código hoje funciona com apenas um dia no caso se buscar mais de um dia com o BETWEEN ele soma os resultados das colunas sacolax e sas03

Comment: Olá! Para melhorar a pergunta, sugiro descrever qual a diferença entre o primeiro e segundo resultado. Caso contrário, quem ler a pergunta vai precisar descobrir sozinho o que tem de diferente entre as 2, o que dificulta o entendimento e fica mais difícil de conseguir a resposta que quer. O título da pergunta pode ser melhorado também, ficou bem "genérico".

Comment: Talvez ele some os resultados de sacolax porque existe um `COALESCE(SUM(o.quantidade), 0) AS sacolax,`?

Comment: A data de "200-05-11" não atende o WHERE "2020-05-14"

Comment: Então, a soma do sacolax é necessária, o que não quero é que se some os dias, com o teste que fiz com BETWEEN ele somava as duas linhas:```295888  5888    2020-05-11 16:00:36 OPERADOR1   20  20  0
295888  5888    2020-05-14 16:00:36 OPERADOR1   49  49  0``` e jogava com a ultima data 2020-05-14, como a seguir: ```295888  5888    2020-05-14 16:00:36 OPERADOR1   69  69  0```

Comment: Não entendi , me desculpe.

Comment: Se é que entendi talvez você deva acrescentar  o campo o.hora à sua cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: quando incluo o o.hora no GROUP BY ele retorna:```
210010 2100 2020-05-14 07:01:07 operador1 2355 63 2292```

Comment: Amigo,
Tentou colocar o group by na data? Assim ele agrupa pela data. No final, você pode colocar assim:
GROUP BY o.matricula , dt_venda ORDER BY hora DESC;